# I'm trying to convert 2019-11-22 11:29:34.56 to epoch timestamp in seconds +1minute in SoapUI groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui

What I want is to take current date and put it to the variable in my test case as something like that 1562239260 using this timestamp converter:

https://www.timestampconvert.com/?go1=true&m=07&d=04&y=2019&hours=13&min=21&sec=000&Submit=++++++Convert+to+timestamp+++++&offset=-1

I tried to put this code as a property value `${=def now=new Date();now.format("yyyy-MM-dd")}` but the format is wrong.

Ok partially I solved the problem `${=def now=new Date();epoch_milis = now.getTime()}`
but i need this time stamp to be ahead for 1minute

Comment: `now.getTime()` returns the timestamp in ms. If you want it in seconds, just divide that by 1000: `now.getTime() / 1000`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the correct answer

```
${=def now=new Date();epoch_milis = now.getTime()+120000}
```

I am ahead of 2 minutes :D

Answer (score 0):

Here it is in pure Groovy:

```
    String myTime = '2019-07-04 13:21:00'
    Date myTimeParsed = Date.parse('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss', myTime)
    assert myTimeParsed.getTime()/1000 == 1562239260

    long epochTime = (myTimeParsed.getTime()/1000) + 60

    import java.time.Instant
    import java.util.Date
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat

    Date sixtyLater = Date.from(Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochTime))
    assert new SimpleDateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss').format(sixtyLater) == '2019-07-04 13:22:00'
```

Comment: @ranger the result above is in seconds. Add a minute's worth of seconds to it... `(myTimeParsed.getTime()/1000) + 60`

Comment: @ranger I edited my answer for you adding 60 seconds, as well as converting it back to Date format